# Why can't the parallel cluster load my R packages?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I need to include, for example, the boot package in my parallel processing. However, clusterEvalQ does not work; as in, the package isn't there on the workers. Below is code and output. I think it has something to do with library locations but the workers see the same library locations.

I've searched similar problems but they were all solved with clusterEvalQ or setting correct library locations... neither of which seem to be my problem. Thanks for any help! This worked previously, but now does not. I have tried removing/reinstalling packages.

```
.libPaths()
> [1] "C:/Users/USERNAME/Documents/R/win-library/3.5"
> [2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.0/library" 

require(boot) # loads

###

cluster <- parallel::makeCluster(2)

parallel::clusterEvalQ(cl   = cluster,
                       expr = {.libPaths()})
> [[1]]
> [1] "C:/Users/USERNAME/Documents/R/win-library/3.5"
> [2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.0/library"                   
>
> [[2]]
> [1] "C:/Users/USERNAME/Documents/R/win-library/3.5"
> [2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.0/library" 

###

parallel::clusterEvalQ(cl   = cluster,
                       expr = {require(boot)})
> [[1]]
> [1] FALSE
>
> [[2]]
> [1] FALSE

###

parallel::stopCluster(cl = cluster)
```

EDIT
After some searching, it seems like the workers are being thrown to a different... something. Running `Sys.info()` results in

```
           sysname            release            version 
         "Windows"         ">= 8 x64"       "build 9200" 
          nodename            machine              login 
         "NODE"                 "x86-64"        "USERNAME" 
              user     effective_user 
           "USERNAME"    "USERNAME"
```

while on the workers is

```
           sysname            release            version 
         "Windows"         "10 x64"       "build 14393" 
          nodename            machine              login 
           "NODE"            "x86-64"           "USERNAME" 
              user     effective_user 
           "USERNAME"     "USERNAME"
```

"NODE" and "USERNAME" were the same on both. So... are the workers being thrown to a different Windows version? System Information on my computer shows the version listed on the workers.

I tried using the Rgui instead of Rstudio, and `Sys.info()` returns the same information as the workers. However, it shows boot is installed. However again, workers created using Rgui (that has same `Sys.info()` as the workers) cannot find the boot package either.

I'm at a loss on this. The code works fine on a different computer.

Comment: What message do you get when you send `library(boot)` to the cluster?

Comment: In line with @Esther's comment: use `library()` - not `require()`.  Also, are you sure that `require(boot)` actually loads/attaches boot when you do it in the main session?

Comment: Using `library` I get `Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) : 
  2 nodes produced errors; first error: cannot open the connection`. boot loads in main session just fine. I converted a `parLapply` to just an `lapply` for now and it works. When I run installed.packages, the clusters return a smaller list than the main session-- but there are some non-base ones. I don't understand, it would seem to me that boot, and other packages, are saved elsewhere but both the main session and the workers are reading the same library paths.

Comment: I've edited the question to add a little more information.

Comment: “cannot open the connection” is a *very* weird error for a `library` call.

Comment: I remember reading about issues like this, with cannot open connection, and they were always wrong directories/library paths

Comment: @Anonymous You’d get a different error message in that case. On the contrary, the error suggests (a) that the package installation is broken (reinstallation should fix that) or that file permissions are messed up: the cluster nodes can find/read the paths, but they cannot open the files.

Comment: They can access some packages though, `require("nnet")` returns true. Install/reinstall doesn't change it. I assume then it must be something with permissions as I have a fairly restricted account on the machine. However this did work a week ago in a different R project (earlier version than this one)